# How stable are version-tagged docker baseimages? Should I make my own copy?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am creating docker images based on base-images from docker.io (for example ubuntu:14.04).

I want my docker-builds to be 100% reproducible. One requirement for this is, that  the baseimage does not change (or if it changes, it is a decision by me to use the changed baseimage).

Can I be sure that a version tagged base image (like ubuntu:14.04) will always be exactly the same?
Or should I make my own copy in my own private repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version tags like ubuntu:14.04 can be expected to change with bug fixes. If you want to be sure you get the exact same image (still containing the fixed bugs) you can use the hash of the image:

```
FROM ubuntu@sha256:4a725d3b3b1c
```

But you can not be sure this exact version will be hosted forever by docker hub.

Safest way is to create your own docker repository server. Push the images you are using to that repository. Use the hash notation to pull the images from your local repos.

```
FROM dockerrepos.yourcompany.com/ubuntu@sha256:4a725d3b3b1c
```